# How to generate weights for non-response?

Tags: predictive-models, missing-data, survey, weights

We would like to use probability weighting to account for non-response in a survey of risk factors for a disease. The fraction of those we approached who refused the survey is very high. Because of data sharing agreements, we have their administrative data, and we've observed that these data can predict non-response quite well.

**Are the rules the same as in other predictive models?** I know that survey analysis with inverse probability weighting is a way to account for non-response. What I do not know is the sound way of building those weights. Is the goal merely to make a probabilistic prediction model? Does that mean split-sample- or cross-validation or the bootstrap should be used to choose factors on the basis of predictive accuracy, like an AUC? Does statistical significance of factors have any bearing?

**On what basis can factors be entered into this method?** Some of our analyses concern estimating prevalence. Does inverse probability weighting mean that the prevalence of a factor is estimated by the Horvitz-Thompson estimator? If so, is there any worry that the weight is built using that very factor? Will the standard errors be accurate in that case? (I noted that weights made by another analyst do just that). What of the causal relationship between weighting-factors and the associations we hope to model? I know that Rubin and Van Buuren say of multiple imputation that it takes no account of causal relationship, that multiple imputation merely uses the data structure to "fill in the blanks". I see this in ways as being like unsupervised learning. But I do not know if the probability-weights and the weighting-factors enjoy such an agnostic relationship with the data and models for which they will be used.